# Dynamic date between date range in mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

Hi Stackoverflow Admin and all member, I have problem when I make datagridview with dynamic column by date.

I have some table for hotel reservation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tp_tblmsroom` (
  `KdRoom` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NmRoom` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `KdRoomType` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`KdRoom`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tp_tblmsroom` (`KdRoom`, `NmRoom`, `KdRoomType`) VALUES
  ('1001', 'Lantai 1 No. 001', 'SNG-SUP'),
  ('1002', 'Lantai 1 No. 002', 'SNG-SUP'),
  ('2001', 'Lantai 2 No. 001', 'SNG-DLX'),
  ('2002', 'Lantai 2 No. 002', 'SNG-DLX'),
  ('3001', 'Lantai 3 No. 001', 'TWN-JRS'),
  ('3002', 'Lantai 3 No. 002', 'TWN-JRS'),
  ('3003', 'Lantai 3 No. 003', 'TWN-JRS'),
  ('4001', 'Lantai 4 No. 001', 'SNG-STE'),
  ('5001', 'Lantai 5 No. 001', 'TWN-PRE'),
  ('6001', 'Lantai 6 No. 001', 'SNG-STD'),
  ('6002', 'Lantai 6 No. 002', 'SNG-STD'),
  ('6003', 'Lantai 6 No. 003', 'SNG-STD'),
  ('6004', 'Lantai 6 No. 004', 'SNG-STD'),
  ('6005', 'Lantai 6 No. 005', 'SNG-STD'),
  ('6006', 'Lantai 6 No. 006', 'TWN-STD'),
  ('6007', 'Lantai 6 No. 007', 'TWN-STD'),
  ('6008', 'Lantai 6 No. 008', 'TWN-STD'),
  ('6009', 'Lantai 6 No. 009', 'TWN-STD');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tp_tblstroomstatus` (
  `KdRoom` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `DateCheck` datetime NOT NULL,
  `KdRoomStatus` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `KdTransaksi` varchar(21) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tp_tblstroomstatus` (`KdRoom`, `DateCheck`, `KdRoomStatus`) VALUES
  ('6006', '2016-11-22 14:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6006', '2016-11-23 14:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6006', '2016-11-23 12:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6006', '2016-11-24 12:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-22 14:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-23 14:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-24 14:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-23 12:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-24 12:00:00', 'BO'),
  ('6007', '2016-11-25 12:00:00', 'BO');
```

I tried to create a query to make the date dynamic when I call between 2 datetimepicker and binding to datagridview in VB.NET.

```
SELECT `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-20 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-20 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-21 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-21 12:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-21 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-21 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-22 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-22 12:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-22 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-22 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-23 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-23 12:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-23 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-23 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-24 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-24 12:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-24 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-24 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-25 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-25 12:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-25 14:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-25 14:00:00`,
  MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = '2016-11-26 12:00:00', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS `2016-11-26 12:00:00`
FROM `tp_tblstroomstatus`
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tp_tblmsroom` ON (`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoom` = `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`)
GROUP BY `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`
```

And then I tried to convert it to:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT
  (DISTINCT CONCAT(
     'MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = ''',
  `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck`,
  ''', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS ',
  `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck`
)
) INTO @sql
FROM `tp_tblstroomstatus`
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tp_tblmsroom` ON (`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoom` = `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`, ', @sql, ' FROM `tp_tblstroomstatus`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tp_tblmsroom` ON (`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoom` = `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`) GROUP BY `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`');
```

But when to try run MySQL code, I get this error.

```
you have an error in your SQL syntax....'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTICT...
```

For additional information, I try looping datagridview using between datetimepicker for generated new columns. And this my VB.NET code:

```
Dim pDateCI As Date = dtpStartRoomRack.Text
Dim pDateCO As Date = dtpEndRoomRack.Text
Dim DayCount As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, pDateCI, pDateCO)
  For i = 0 To DayCount - 1
    .Columns.Add(i, (Format(pDateCI, "yyyy/MM/dd") & " " & Format(pTimeCI, "HH:mm:ss"))) 'format pDateCI date use for call mysql data in checkdate column like 2016-11-21 14:00:00'
    .Columns.Add(i, (Format(pDateCI.AddDays(1), "yyyy/MM/dd") & " " & Format(pTimeCO, "HH:mm:ss"))) 'format pDateCO date use for call mysql data in checkdate column like 2016-11-22 12:00:00'
    pDateCI = pDateCI.AddDays(1)
  Next
```

How can I resolved my problem please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Henry... thanks for crosscheck  my questions sir... :)

Comment: You should edit your question and post the error you're getting :)

Comment: I get an error "you have an error in your SQL syntax....'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTICT..." Sir..

Comment: Please do not replace your original question with a new; use a new post for a next question.

Answer (score 0):

Wendy, I'm going to take a guess here. I think your query is fine and you have a break where you shouldn't have one. Look at the second line below and keep that together on one row and then try to run your query.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
     'MAX(IF(`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck` = ''',
  `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck`,
  ''', `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoomStatus`, '')) AS ',
  `tp_tblstroomstatus`.`DateCheck`
)
) INTO @sql
FROM `tp_tblstroomstatus`
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tp_tblmsroom` ON (`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoom` = `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`, ', @sql, ' FROM `tp_tblstroomstatus`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `tp_tblmsroom` ON (`tp_tblstroomstatus`.`KdRoom` = `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`) GROUP BY `tp_tblmsroom`.`KdRoom`');
```

Comment: Thank you sir..that's worked... :D... But I have new problem to insert code "where' date range from datetimepicker vb.net to mysql? I tried to insert "where" after "from",but doesn't worked sir.

Comment: Wendy, when someone answers your original question correctly you mark it as correct, you don't change the question, after they get you paste the original issue. You ask a new question on stack overflow. The people who spent time answering your original question deserves the upvote and marking it as the correct solution for answering it. Someone else can have the same problem, and will never see the right answer, because the question changed.  When you ask a new question more eyes will see it, because it's new question not a day old. I suggest removing your edit, and asking a new question.